# Update an email in an active journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

I have an active journey with a sent email step in it. 
If I make changes in the email attached to this journey, will the email get updates automatically, or do I need to make a new draft/version of the journey for it to get updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't get updated automatically, but you can manually publish the changes to the triggered send via Email Studio as described here: [Triggered Email Change Process](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/triggered_emails/triggered_emails_guide/triggered_email_change_process/)

The triggered send for a journey's email send activity can be found in `Email Studio` -> `Interactions`  under `Messages` -> `Email` -> `Journey Builder Sends` -> `[Journey Name]` -> `[Version X]` -> `[Email Send Activity Name]`

**Edit:** Since the January '17 release, it should also be possible from within Journey Builder. Just got to the Details and Configuration dialog, perform changes and click done. For further details please check out the following documentation page: [Update an Email in a Running Journey](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/configuring_the_send_email_activity/update_an_email_in_a_running_journey/)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that its just "triggered Sends" journey builder are using.