# Journey Activated - Change to Wait times - New Version

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, versioning

I have a journey working and had made the journey have a wait + time of 1 day until 10:00am.  Unbeknownst to me was the fact that MC operates on a 24hr period, and not the calendar.

Anyway - That made me want to change the cadence of the wait times to make sure I was sending email at optimal times.

Does this require me to stop Version 1 and create a new version?
What if I want to play with the wait times on Version 2 after I activate that one?  Another version?

How would that effect my audience?  Does the rule 'never re-enter' apply to the contacts that have already been through a previous Version of the journey?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to create a new version if you want to change the wait times in your journey. The current population of your journey will not be affected by these changes, if you don't force them to exit. So just activating the new version will let the subscribers of your old version finish this journey and only new contacts will enter the new version.

The re-entry settings apply to all versions of a journey, so a contant won't enter a new version:

> Select No re-entry if contacts cannot enter the journey again after a previous entry. This setting applies across all versions of a journey.  Once you activate the journey, you cannot change this option.
> (Source: [Journey Settings documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/interaction_settings/))

Comment: Also be aware that if you eject people, you cannot inject people to the same point in the journey, they will start a new.

Comment: Follow-up question.  Can I force an audience to exit so I can have them re-enter in a new version if that audience hasn't been messaged?

Comment: Yes, this happens if you select "Stop This Version" or "Stop All Versions" (see [Stop a Journey in the documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/interaction_versions/stop_a_journey/)). They aren't ejected if you just activate the new version. However you need to select a re-entry mode that allows them to be injected into a new version. If the audience received a message or not doesn't make a difference here.

Comment: @MarkusSlabina  Would you say that Journey Builder doesn't provide a campaign to be very nimble with changes to emails/wait times, etc.?

Comment: Changes in emails could be done using the triggered sends directly some time ago and since one of the last releases this can be done directly within a running version in journey builder (how to do this can be found here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/155442/36218). But for wait times there is no way getting around a new journey version, but maybe this will get more flexible in the future. However this "fixedness" could serve a purpose as comparability of changes regarding the effect on the goal attainment would be affected if too much changes within a running interaction are allowed.